# SCD0 implementation using staging and taget table

Tags: sql, scd

I'm looking for a one transaction query that would allow me to truncate a target table first and insert everything from staging table to target table. I tried using merge into, but that requires using keys and is not very generic. Any thoughts?

Comment: Please can you tag your question with the DBMS you are using. However, it is not possible to truncate a table and then insert data into it with a single query - it will always take 2 "queries". Obviously, you can put both statements in a single transaction (assuming your DBMS supports this)

Comment: I'm using BigQuery. It doesn't necesarilly have to be truncate and insert, I'm open to some suggestions that would do the same job in one query like I previously tried to do with merge but failed to do it generic.